# Where to find the Windows 10 license key on the surface book?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface, license-key

Where can one find the key of the installed windows 10 operating system on the surface book?

I tried to find it on the case and asked google but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: You don't have any physical proof of a license except for the COA sticker on the device itself which does not have the key printed on it.  The license key is embedded into the firmware on the device and is not required to install or activate Windows 10.  This means if the device is repaired, and the motherboard replaced, you will received a new license since the previous one would technically not be authorized for the new motherboard.

Comment: If you are desperate to find the the key embedded in the firmware, there is a procedure you can go through to read the motherboard data and extract it. I've done it, but I cannot now find the link I used; however, I found that Method 1 in [this link](https://itsolutionsblog.net/3-ways-to-extract-the-windows-8-product-key/) describes how I did it. I though I'd need it for a re-installation of W8, but I didn't.

Comment: You can get the key but activation is based on a digital entitlement on Windows 10 so it's not required.  The key was detected with Windows 8 and if it wasn't then it would be required.  Windows 7 required you to input it when Windows was installed

Comment: When I do a factory reset on my Surface every year to sell it when I buy a new one, it always asks whoever I sold it to for this when they first start the laptop. It prompts them to pay $49 for a new license otherwise. Insidious on Microsoft's part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/product-key-windows-10):

> How to find your product key depends on how you bought your copy of
>   Windows 10:
>
> - If you bought Windows 10 from an authorized retailer, the product key will be on a label inside the box it came in.
> - If you bought a digital copy of Windows 10 from a Microsoft website,    the product key will be in the confirmation email you received after buying it or will be distributed digitally as an entitlement, in which case you won't receive a product key. For example, if you upgraded to Windows 10 for free, you'll receive an entitlement instead of a product key.
> - If you bought a new PC running Windows 10, the product key will be    pre–installed on your PC and your PC will automatically be activated, included with the packaging the PC came in, or included on the Certificate of Authenticity (COA) attached to the PC.

I would assume it is in the box the Surface Book came in.

Comment: Actually it is activated through the BIOS. Not sure how this technique was called but the license is basically stored in your BIOS and activates Windows 10 automatically

Comment: Not sure what your comment is for. Are you just agreeing with the third bullet point in my answer?

Answer (score 9):

You can get the product key using:

```
wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

Note: Please run the command with admin privileges ii won't work directly